# How to use global variables on a state machine

Tags: c, global-variables, state-machine

I made this state machine :

```
 enum states { STATE_ENTRY, STATE_....} current_state;
 enum events { EVENT_OK, EVENT_FAIL,EVENT_REPEAT, MAX_EVENTS } event;
 void (*const state_table [MAX_STATES][MAX_EVENTS]) (void) = {
   { action_entry , action_entry_fail , action_entry_repeat }, /* 
                                                  procedures for state 1 */
  ......}

void main (void){
   event = get_new_event (); /* get the next event to process */
   if (((event >= 0) && (event < MAX_EVENTS))
   && ((current_state >= 0) && (current_state < MAX_STATES))) {
      state_table [current_state][event] (); /* call the action procedure */
      printf("OK 0");
   } else {
      /* invalid event/state - handle appropriately */
         }
}
```

When I modify a global variable in one state the global variable remain the same , and I need that variable in all the states . Do you now what could be the problem ? 
My Global variable is this structure:

```
  #if (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_32)
     typedef uint32_t word;
     #define word_length 32
     typedef struct BigNumber {
     word words[64];
    } BigNumber;
   #elif (CPU_TYPE == CPU_TYPE_16)
    typedef uint16_t word;
    #define word_length 16
    typedef struct BigNumber {
    word words[128];
    } BigNumber;
   #else
     #error Unsupported CPU_TYPE
  #endif
  BigNumber number1 , number2;

 Here is how I modify:
 //iterator is a number from where I start to modify,
 //I already modified on the same way up to the iterator
 for(i=iterator+1;i<32;i++){
     nr_rand1=661;
     nr_rand2=1601;
     nr_rand3=1873;
     number2.words[i]=(nr_rand1<<21) | (nr_rand2<<11) | (nr_rand3);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add actual code segment where you are modifying global variable?

Comment: Do you have a strict requirement for representing the FSM as a (2D) array of pointers to functions? I find it so complicated that you must have some benefit somewhere else for having chosen it.

Comment: @PopoviciSebi - Don't add code as comment. Instead edit you question so the code becomes part of question itself. Try to provide a small but complete example that generates the problem so that we can repeat it in our own system.

Comment: @Remo.D It is one of the simplest models that I found ... I need a state machine for a rsa signature ,to be  implemented on a 32 bit board , and I am new in this

Comment: Your approach is ok but you don't show us enough code to help you. Try to convert your code to a short simplified example that can be compiled as is. Maybe you'll find the bug while making that simplified example ;-)

Comment: Do you have a local variable named `number2`? That would explain it as the local variable would shadow the global.

Comment: Also you may have copied the typedef and variable declaration wrong. As they are now they could not compile.

Comment: @4386427  I have only one variable , the global one .

Comment: Are all the functions in the same file? If not, did you declared `number2` as `extern` in all files but one?

Comment: @PopoviciSebi, I've edited the source so it can compile, please check if it's what you actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer - rather it is a comment. But it is too big to fit the comment field so I post it here for now.

The code posted in the question is not sufficient to find the root cause. You need to post a minimal but complete example that shows the problem.

Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t word;
#define word_length 32
typedef struct BigNumber {
  word words[4];
} BigNumber;

BigNumber number2;

enum states { STATE_0, STATE_1} current_state;
enum events { EVENT_A, EVENT_B } event;

void f1(void)
{
  int i;
  current_state = STATE_1;
  for (i=0; i<4; ++i) number2.words[i] = i;
}

void f2(void)
{
  int i;
  current_state = STATE_0;
  for (i=0; i<4; ++i) number2.words[i] = 42 + i*i;
}

void (*const state_table [2][2]) (void) =
{
    { f1 , f1 },
    { f2 , f2 }
};


int main (void){
  current_state = STATE_0;

  event = EVENT_A;
  state_table [current_state][event] (); /* call the action procedure */
  printf("%u %u %u %u\n", number2.words[0], number2.words[1], number2.words[2], number2.words[3]);

  event = EVENT_B;
  state_table [current_state][event] (); /* call the action procedure */
  printf("%u %u %u %u\n", number2.words[0], number2.words[1], number2.words[2], number2.words[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

The above can be considered minimal and complete. Now update this code with a few of your own functions and post that as the question (if it still fails).

My code doesn't fail.

Output:

```
0 1 2 3
42 43 46 51
```

Comment: Thank you , I took all functions and put them on this smaller StMachine ,and then and then just copy paste them back and it looks that it worked , still don't know what was the problem , but now it works :-) , thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is just in case you may want to change your approach for defining the FSM. I'll show you with an example; say you have the following FSM:

[image]

You may represent it as:

```
void function process() {
   fsm {
     fsmSTATE(S) {
       /* do your entry actions heare */
       event = getevent();
       /* do you actions here */
       if (event.char == 'a') fsmGOTO(A); 
       else fsmGOTO(E);
     }

     fsmSTATE(A) {
       event = getevent();
       if (event.char == 'b' || event.char == 'B') fsmGOTO(B); 
       else fsmGOTO(E);
     }

     fsmSTATE(B) {
       event = getevent();
       if (event.char == 'a' ) fsmGOTO(A); 
       else fsmGOTO(E);
     }
     fsmSTATE(E) {
       /* done with the FSM. Bye bye! */
     }
   }
}
```

I do claim (but I believe someone will disagree) that this is simpler,  much more readable and directly conveys the structure of the FSM than using a table. Even if I didn't put the image, drawing the FSM diagram would be rather easy.

To get this you just have to define the `fsmXXX` stuff as follows:

```
#define fsm            
#define fsmGOTO(x)    goto fsm_state_##x
#define fsmSTATE(x)   fsm_state_##x :
```

Comment: Thank you , I am going to try this model ,it look's ok for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the code that changese `number2`:

```
for(i=iterator+1;i<32;i){
    nr_rand1=661;
    nr_rand2=1601;
    nr_rand3=1873;
    number2.words[i]=(nr_rand1<<21) | (nr_rand2<<11) | (nr_rand3);
}
```

I can't fail to note that:

- `i` is never incremented, so just one element of the array is changed (`iterator+1`) over an infinite loop;
- even if `i` would be incremented, only the a portion of the `words` array it's changed depending on the value of `iterator` (but this might be the intended behaviour).
- unless `iterator` can be `-1`, the element `words[0]` is never changed (again this could be the intended behaviour).

I would check if this is really what you intended to do.

If you're sure that it's just a visibility problem (since you said that when you declare it as local it worked as expected), the only other thing that I can think of is that you have the functions in one file and the main (or where you do your checks) in another.

Then you include the same `.h` header in both files and you end up (due to the linker you're using) with two different `number2` because you did not declare it as `extern` in one of the two files.
Your compiler (or, better, the linker) should have (at least) warned you about this, did you check the compilation messages?

Comment: Good catch - this is probably it :-)

Comment: I modified the increment  (wrong copy paste  here), but the problem is on state machine or global memory , because if I declare them inside the state it is working but I need the structures (modified) on the next state